# UITableView and CALayer confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, calayer

I got a very simple `UITableViewCell` subclass. `MyTableViewCell.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    CALayer *backgroundLayer;
}

@end
```

`MyTableViewCell.m`:

```
#import "MyTableViewCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@implementation MyTableViewCell


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        backgroundLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        [backgroundLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]];
        [[self layer] addSublayer:backgroundLayer];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    [backgroundLayer setFrame:[layer frame]];
    [super layoutSublayersOfLayer:layer];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [backgroundLayer release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Bizarrely, here's the result:[image].

Can someone explain this?! Why doesn't the layer paint in all cells but only every second cell?

EDIT: Here's my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"cellReuseIdentifier";

MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] autorelease];

return cell;
```

Comment: It could be something in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, can you post your implementation of this method?

Comment: Can't think of anything obviously wrong with the code. But note that the reference for the layer method says it returns "the initialized CALayer object or nil if initialization is not successful." Maybe check that it isn't returning nil.

Comment: @jjoelson: Me neither. When I scroll around, everything get's f*cked up, most cells disappear completely... Maybe it's a bug in Apple's code? EDIT: It never returns nil.

Comment: Actually, it could be a mem management issue. You should retain the CALayer object since you are keeping it in an ivar (and of course release it in dealloc). I'm not sure if this is the problem since adding it as a sublayer should prevent it from being deallocated, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Also, you might want to try setting the frame of the layer in your initialization method.

Comment: @jjoelson: OK, found the problem. I forgot that the frame's origin must obviously be `CGPointZero`! That also explains why every second row got drawn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this method did the trick:

```
- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    CGRect frame = [layer frame];
    frame.origin = CGPointZero;
    [backgroundLayer setFrame:frame];
    [super layoutSublayersOfLayer:layer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not related to your question, you should add your layers to [self.contentView layer]. Otherwise editing functionality like delete-swipe will not render correctly.